# Android Get Setting "Lock instantly with power key" programmatically

Tags: android, settings, system, lockscreen

I need to get "Lock instantly with power key" setting in Settings->Device->Lock Screen -> Lock instantly with power key.

However, I can get "Lock Automatically after" setting as followed:

```
ContentResolver mResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
long timeout = Settings.Secure.getLong(mResolver, "lock_screen_lock_after_timeout", 0);
```

Thank you.